Reading Guides for Husserl's Logical Investigations?
Can anyone recommend a reading guide to accompany Husserl's Logical Investigations? I am not referring to general introductions to his thought, but specifically to the LI.
I can read in english, french, spanish and german.
Thanks in advance.

Not exactly a reading guide (I am not aware of one in English), but Dahlstrom's volume on LI  has good reviews and "is designed to help students and specialists alike work their way through Husserl's expansive text by bringing together in a single volume six self-contained, expository yet critical essays." You may also find useful the syllabus of Sandmeyer's seminar on reading LI that has some secondary sources recommended for specific parts.

Maybe useful Mohanty

Perhaps to read guides for Husserl's Logical Investigation is just to read his opposing view of logic aka the popular and well-known psychologism as discussed in an interesting recent post in this site...
